# Checking variable data with Dual

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to get either Y or N from single select statement :

I have  total 7 variables :

```
X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6 and X7
```

if any of the variables X1 to X7 having value '100'  then 'Yes' else 'No'.

suppose take :

```
x1=100
x2=101
x3=null
x4=null
x5=null
x6=null
x7=null
```

Then I need result 'Yes'.

```
x1=101
x2=101
x3=null
x4=null
x5=null
x6=null
x7=null
```

Then I need result 'No'.

Regards,

Chaitu

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN 100 IN (:X1, :X2, :X3, :X4, :X5, :X6, :X7) THEN
                'Yes'
        ELSE
                'No'
        END
FROM    dual
```

Comment: @user3457336: it is, but why?

Comment: @user3457336 - re: using DECODE to solve this problem - I'm sure there is. Why don't you give it a try and let us know what you come up with?